# request for member ‘s’ in something not a structure or union

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

This is my .lex file:

```
"Sphere"        {return SPHERE;}
"("         {return LBRACKET;}
")"         {return RBRACKET;}
"."         {return DOT;}
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    {yylval.s = yytext; return NAME;}

[ \t\n]+    /* ignore */
.   return yytext[0];
```

This is my bison .y file:

```
%union {
  char* s;
  double d;
  int i;
} 

/* Operators */

/* Tokens */
%token ALPHANUM
%token SPHERE
%token LBRACKET
%token RBRACKET
%token DOT
%token NAME

/* type declarations */
%type<s> NAME

%%

sentence: SPHERE LBRACKET NAME RBRACKET DOT
{
    printf("%i\n", $3);
}
 ;
```

The error I get is:

"request for member ‘s’ in something not a structure or union"

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, `NAME` is a terminal. Therefore, the correct way of declaring its type is this:

```
%token <s> NAME
```

`%type` is used only for nonterminals.